# Use PowerShell to download hosted mailboxes?

Tags: powershell, exchange

TL;DR:

I need to download all the mailboxes from a remote hosted exchange server, and I would prefer to do it without purchasing an archiving utility such as MailStore. I have access to an admin account with FullAccess permissions to all mailboxes.

(I am trying to not to [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) this... so I am open to suggestions).

Background:
We are migrating a client from hosted exchange to on-premise. We had asked the the losing provider to export all mailboxes to PST, but they are not cooperating (even after we offered to pay for consulting time to do it!).

There are 50+ mailboxes (some 40GB+), and we really don't want to load each one in outlook to download them. Is there a way to script this with PowerShell? The losing provider did give us an admin account with FullAccess permissions to all mailboxes.

Comment: https://exchange-server-guide.blogspot.com/2015/11/export-edb-mailbox-to-pst-using-powershell.html

Comment: This link is for a normal export request, which requires LAN access to use UNC paths, and thus, seems not applicable to our situation. We need to script the download and access it via OWA or similar. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you get access to the server, or at least VPN access to the network? Maybe a jump box?

Comment: No, The losing provider is not cooperating in any way. No such access is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no PowerShell type solution, we ended up using https://www.mailstore.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have Administrator Details, you can also try this free version of the [utility](https://steemit.com/export/@ellestephen/export-exchange-contacts-to-pst-file-format-without-powershell-command), as it needs only Administrator Credentials details to access the Exchange mailboxes and allow the user to preview not only Exchange Mailboxes but also subdomain user to export data into PST format.